# How do I find a word and add text after it in a .txt file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I find a word (e.g. "/dn") in a text file and add on the next line another word (e.g. "/period")?

I'd like to execute it using MS DOS.

I mean this "/dn" (after /dn is space) is one word (not a fragment of the text, but the whole word--after /dn can be other word on the same line) which I want to find and then after it on the next new line, not replacing the other lines and other words. I mean create a new line between already existing lines.

For example, if I have this input file:

```
/dn
/name
```

I want this output:

```
/dn
/period
/name
```

and "/" symbol should be with dn, not without it.

Comment: On the next line? Where on the next line? Should it replace what is currently in the next line? Inserta a new line? Insert the text at the beginning of the next line? Please [edit] your question, show us a simple example input and the output you want to see from it.

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question and show us an example of your input and your desired output.

Comment: and "/" symbol should be with "dn", not without it

Comment: Thanks. So, will `/dn` *always* be the only word in the line? Can you have more than one `/dn` on the same line? What if you have `/dna`, does that count? Can you have spaces before or after the `/dn`?

Comment: of course /dn can be not only word on the one line. It doesn't matter how much words on "/dn" 's line and /dn it is first word on this line. About /dna it doesn't count /dn. after /dn can be space

Comment: All of these are very important details. Don't say "of course" when your question says that `/dn` is the "single word on one line". This is why it is important to show us representative examples of your data.

Comment: How can i delete this question?

Answer (score 10):

#### 1. Using `sed` append

If you want a completely new line with the word `/period` after each line containing `/dn` then use `sed` append:

```
sed '\:\dn:a/period' filename
```

the output for your sample would be:

```
/dn
/period
/name
```

#### 1. Notes

- `:\dn:` search for `\dn`
- `a/period` append `/period` to the next line (a new line).

---

#### 2. Search and append to the end of next line

If you want the `/period` at the end of the next line then use it like this:

```
sed ':/dn: { N; s:$:/period: }' filename
```

Here is a sample input:

```
/dn
/name
```

and the output:

```
/dn
/name /period
```

#### 2. Notes

First we are searching for lines with `/dn`, then we add the `/period` at the end of (`$`) next line (`N;`).

Comment: The OP is very hard to understand, but I think they want the `/period` to be printed on the *next* line.

Comment: Updated the answer ;)

Comment: for the noobs, can you show full cmd code. using my expamle

Comment: @Lunsy updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `file.txt` contains string `/dn` then You can run this command:

```
$ grep -i "\/dn" file.txt | xargs -I{} printf "%s\n/period" {}
```

It will print

```
/dn
/period
```

Comment: i) why are you making this case insensitive? That will also match `Dn/`, `dN/` and `DN/`. The OP only specified `dn`/. ii) What's the point of the `grep`? That will print the entire line matching `dn/`, not the `dn/` alone. More importantly, this will ignore all lines that don't have `/dn`, so change the OP's input.  iii) you don't actually need the `-I{}` or `{}`, that's the default behavior of `xargs`. iv) you might want to add a `\n` after the `/period` as well. vi) You also don't need to escape the `/` for `grep`: `grep /dn file.txt` works fine.